# C# Web Client clear all data

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

I have website which gives me different value (example: `value="c04f8d84708f9865f4e04802c51c2f90"`) every time when I clear cookies in my standard browsers (Firefox, Chrome...). 
But when I use client I get always same value, my code:

```
WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
                client1.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            client1.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            string html = client1.DownloadString("website");
            client1.Dispose();
```

How I can clear all data/cookies so I can get different value ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
```

Comment: 'WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultRequestHeaders' and no extension method 'DefaultRequestHeaders' accepting a first argument of type 'WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you show me it on example, I just tried it with HttpWebRequest but it does not work and I can't find any example for httpClient

Comment: Also I use Windows Form application

Answer (score 0):

use HttpRequest object instead of WebClient, and hopefully (if you place your doubts in WebClient) everything will be solved. If it wasn't solved with HttpRequest, then the problem really IS somewhere else.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with HttpWebRequest but I don't know how to clear cookies

Comment: You could do something like this.

CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();
var cookies = c.GetCookies(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
foreach (Cookie co in cookies)
{
  co.Expires = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
}

This will expire all cookies for the domain you specify.